# Keeping only one column after join

Tags: pandas

For the following code

```
d = {'col1': [33,34], 'col2': [1,2]}
d1 = {'col3': [33,34], 'col4': [3,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)    
myDF=pd.merge(df, df1, how='inner', left_on=['col1'], right_on=['col3'])
```

in `myDF`, it kept two columns (`col1` and `col3`), is there a way to keep either one column (`col1` or `col3`) with `merge` function? (of course I can drop a column by applying `drop` later on after `merge`, just want to see is it possible to simplify the step.)

Answer (score 2):

Use `rename` column, so output is only one column and also is not necessary use `left_on` and `right_on` parameters, because `on` is enough:

```
myDF=pd.merge(df.rename(columns={'col1':'col3'}), df1, on='col3')
print (myDF)
   col3  col2  col4
0    33     1     3
1    34     2     4
```

---

```
myDF=pd.merge(df, df1.rename(columns={'col3':'col1'}), on='col1')
print (myDF)
   col1  col2  col4
0    33     1     3
1    34     2     4
```